# Show every break in the y-axis ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I have this dataframe

```
   year   month Avdischarge 
37 2018     1    740.5200          
38 2018     2    376.8050          
39 2018     3    269.2800         
40 2018     4    195.8825         
41 2018     5    100.9800          
42 2018     6     99.5775
```

I want to show the exact values of discharge in the y -axis. 
When I plotted with

```
q<-ggplot(data, aes(month, Avdischarge, group= 1))+ 
  geom_line(color='royalblue1', size=1.5, alpha=0.9)
```

I get in the y-axis 200, 400, 600.

But I want to show the six values of discharge that I have, matching each month.
What can I add?

Comment: You can use those values as your axis breaks

Comment: Following the @camille advice (+1), you could add this in the end  `+ scale_y_continuous(breaks= data$Avdischarge) `.

Comment: When I add that, the y-axis disappears

Answer (score 3):

If you make the y-axis have breaks for each discharge you'll actually end up getting labels stacked on top of each other which is not very useful for the user of the plot. I propose putting label markers on each point so that you can keep the y-axis clean while still conveying information to your users. See my code below:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat <- tribble(~"year",   ~"month", ~"Avdischarge",
 2018,     1,    740.5200,          
 2018,     2,    376.8050,          
 2018,     3,    269.2800,         
 2018,     4,    195.8825,         
 2018,     5,    100.9800,          
 2018,     6,     99.5775)

ggplot(dat, aes(month, Avdischarge, group= 1))+ 
    geom_line(color='royalblue1', size=1.5, alpha=0.9) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = dat$Avdischarge)
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(dat, aes(month, Avdischarge, group= 1))+ 
    geom_line(color='royalblue1', size=1.5, alpha=0.9) +
    geom_point(color='royalblue1') + 
    geom_text(aes(label = Avdischarge), 
              nudge_y = 15, nudge_x = .2, color='royalblue1') + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:6)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

You can play with `nudge_x` and `nudge_y` to get the labels exactly where you want them.